# Why does "border-top:none" put the rest of my css out of place?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

So basically i have an small registration form, and im having css problems with the input boxes, and i basically want it to have a flat look (no side borders or top border) just the the bottom border.

In chrome it works fine, it doesnt mess up the position of the input forms. but in IE and Firefox it misplaces it. If I remove "border-top: none;" it fixes it, but obviously adds that border on the top that i dont want. Any tips on how to fix this?

Here's the part of css used to modify the input box(es).

```
    #sign_up .sprited {
    outline: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #7A7A7A;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Here is my sign_up_form

```
 <div id="sign_up_form">
                <div class="Labeltxt">Full Name :</div>
                <div class="RoundtxtBox">
                    <input type="text" name="fname" value="" class="sprited">
                </div>
                <div class="Labeltxt">Email Id :</div>
                <div class="RoundtxtBox">
                    <input type="text" name="uemail" value="" class="sprited">
                </div>
                <div class="Labeltxt">Password :</div>
                <div class="RoundtxtBox">
                    <input type="password" name="upassword" value="" class="sprited">
                </div>
                <div id="actions">
                    <a href="#" id="cancel" class="close form_button">Cancel</a>
                    <input type="submit" class="regsub" name="submit" value="Join" />
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
            <!--<a href="#" class="close" id="close_x">close</a>-->
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the future, you should always use `border:0;`and `border-top:0;` instead of `border-top:none;`. That would probably fix the problem and it is the correct way to write it. Also, for your website to load faster, you could turn this:

```
-moz-border-radius: 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;
-khtml-border-radius: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;
```

into this:

```
-moz-border-radius: 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-khtml-border-radius: 0;
border-radius: 0;
```

Just remove the type of unit it is. 0 is the same in every unit type.

Answer (score 0):

It's a floating issue on the `input` container. What you should try doing is placing your label and input into a container `div`, and `float` the `label` and `input` to the left. Then place a `div` which will clear the `float`.

That's usually the technique I use.
Let me know if it's unclear.

CSS:

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label>Full Name: </label>
    <input type="text" ... />
    <div class="clear">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, sadly I tried multiple variations and I was not able to make it work :/ I edited my question with the "sign_up_form", in hopes you could provide a bit more help, if you don't mind. Thank you so much.

Comment: i fixed it by changing it to,  border-top-color: transparent;